# How to get specific data from Firebase Firestore and Create a Line Graph in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to Android Studio and I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve a particular data from the Firebase Firestore Database and present that data into a Line Graph.

At the moment I have created the database as you can see below: 
[image]

All I want to do is to show the glucose amount which is a Double in a Line graph.

If someone could please help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Below I am showing the code that I have started with:

```
public class Chart extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference ref = (CollectionReference) firestore .collection("BGAndCarbohydrate");

    FirebaseAuth auth;

    String userID;

    GraphView graph;
    LineGraphSeries series;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_glucose_chart);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        series = new LineGraphSeries();
        graph.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I  understand correctly- you want to query the documents in `BDAndCarbohydrate` collection and then plot the `glucoseAmount` value against `currentDateAndTime` in a line graph.

In that case, first query the documents sorted by currentDateAndTime, and then iterate through the result to create data points for each document, and then add these data points to your series.

```
List<DataPoint> datapoints = new ArrayList();

Query query = firestore.collection("BDAndCarbohydrate")
                            .orderBy("currentDateAndTime");

query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Successfully fetched data from firestore");

                            int index = 0;
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot.getResult()) {
                                Map data = document.getData();
                                Double glucoseAmount = data.get("glucoseAmount");

                                datapoints.add(new DataPoint(glucoseAmount, index));
                                index++;

                            }
                        }
                    });

//Add the datapoints to the series here..
```

You can use where/startAfter/limit etc. in that query to filter out some documents if needed.

I didn't test this code so please assume it to be a pseudocode and modify as needed.

Comment: Another question, how do I add the datapoints to the series? Is it like this: graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        series = new LineGraphSeries();
        graph.addSeries(series);

Comment: That should depend on the library you're using. Maybe something like- `LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(datapoints.toArray());  graph.addSeries(series);`

Comment: I have tried that, but I get this error now: 'LineGraphSeries(com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint[])' in 'com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Object[])'

Comment: try `LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints.toArray(new DataPoint[dataPoints.size()]));`

Comment: Oh Wow. Thank you so much for the help Asif, it worked.